# Compiling React Native for Windows (on Windows)

Tags: windows, react-native, react-native-windows

Has anyone successfully compiled and run a Windows (UWP) app on a Windows (10) machine using React Native?

I've built an app, it's working in the Android emulator. I ran through the instructions from Microsoft [here](https://www.microsoft.com/developerblog/real-life-code/2016/05/27/Creating-Universal-Windows-Apps-with-React-Native.html) and [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html).

I am using VS Code for my editor... should I be using Visual Studio?

I ran these commands to convert existing project to a 'Windows' project which adds the Windows file structure. That works.

```
npm install --save-dev rnpm-plugin-windows
react-native windows
```

I ran:

```
react-native run-windows
```

Which basically works but fails at the end.

At this point in the loading I get an error:

```
Building C:/Users/..../MyApp/windows/MyApp.sln
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
```

The rest of it seems to install fine but at the end...

```
Press Enter to continue...:
Failed to deploy: Command failed: CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n=
```

I Googled this error and got literally zero results. Anyone have something that could help me get over this hump?

Am I supposed to have a Windows Emulator on my machine like the Android emulator or does it just run like any other program?

Also, I'm not 'allowed' to create a new tag unless I have 1500 magic unicorn points so could someone please create react-native-windows tag for future users?

Comment: I can't see creating a new tag for a pretty narrow question like this.

Comment: There are react-native-android and react-native-ios tags so I'm thinking one related to windows would be helpful.

Comment: Also check this: https://forums.plex.tv/discussion/62776/windows-app-unable-to-connect-to-localhost-server

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n=MyApp
```

Where 'MyApp' is the name of your project folder.

Thanks @Onorio Catenacci for the [link](https://forums.plex.tv/discussion/62776/windows-app-unable-to-connect-to-localhost-server) that had the clues to put it together.

Comment: And to answer another of my questions it runs in standalone container. No emulator needed I guess unless you want it to emulate a specific phone.